# QuickReports Multicolumn

Tags: delphi, quickreports

I am coding with Embarcadero Delphi 10.1 Berlin...
When the number of columns in the QuickReport(v6) is more than one, the columns are displayed from left to right by default. How to start right?

I want to show columns from right to left?

Comment: AFAIK, QR does not support doing so.

Comment: Columns in a QuickReport are a layout convenience. There is no programmatic advantage to using columns. The same results can be obtained without using columns: you still need to populate your TQRLabels as you require them to be populated.

Comment: @FreddieBell: Actually, that's not always true. If you're printing a report (for instance, labels) attached to a database, you define one label at the top left of the report, and attach database fields to the QR data-aware labels, and QR takes care of the rest for you automatically. For non-database reports, you use the control's OnNeedData event to populate the labels and QR still takes care of the rest for you.

Comment: @Ken White. I usually work with bands, and I don't use OnNeedData except for labels and asymmetric reports. So my comment remains true for that situation. The point here is that the OP can achieve what he needs to achieve, if he does the coding himself instead of relying on the automated facilities.